# Transaction reverts when i try to call a specific function of another smart contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, function-call

i'm facing a weird issue and i can't understand why it's happening after quadraple checking everything,

i have a token which has USDT internal liquidity,
i also have matrix contract which is in charge of buying and selling the token,
and no address can buy or sell the token exept the matrix contract.

this function is in charge of buying new tokens with underlying asset (USDT):

```
 function _stakeUnderlyingAsset(uint256 numTokens, address recipient)
        internal
        returns (bool)
    {
        // make sure it's not locked
        require(
            Token_Activated || msg.sender == _owner || isMatrix[msg.sender],
            "Token is Currently Locked Inside the Matrix"
        );
        // user's underlying balance
        uint256 userTokenBalance = IERC20(_underlying).balanceOf(msg.sender);
        // ensure user has enough to send
        require(
            userTokenBalance > 0 && numTokens <= userTokenBalance,
            "Insufficient Balance"
        );
        // calculate price change
        uint256 oldPrice = _calculatePrice();
        // previous amount of underlying asset before any are received
        uint256 prevTokenAmount = IERC20(_underlying).balanceOf(address(this));
        // move asset into this contract
        bool success = IERC20(_underlying).transferFrom(
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            numTokens
        );
        // balance of underlying asset after transfer
        uint256 currentTokenAmount = IERC20(_underlying).balanceOf(
            address(this)
        );
        // number of Tokens we have purchased
        uint256 difference = currentTokenAmount.sub(prevTokenAmount);
        // ensure nothing unexpected happened
        require(
            difference <= numTokens && difference > 0,
            "Failure on Token Evaluation"
        );
        // ensure a successful transfer
        require(success, "Failure On Token TransferFrom");
        // if this is the first purchase, use new amount
        prevTokenAmount = prevTokenAmount == 0
            ? currentTokenAmount
            : prevTokenAmount;
        // Emit Staked
        emit TokenStaked(difference, recipient);
        // Handle Minting
        return _handleMinting(recipient, difference, prevTokenAmount, oldPrice);
    }
```

this one is in charge of selling tokens:

```
function _sell(uint256 tokenAmount, address recipient) internal {
require(tokenAmount > 0 && _balances[msg.sender] >= tokenAmount);
// calculate price change
uint256 oldPrice = _calculatePrice();
// fee exempt
bool takeFee = !isFeeExempt[msg.sender];

// tokens post fee to swap for underlying asset
uint256 tokensToSwap = takeFee
    ? tokenAmount.mul(sellFee).div(feeDenominator)
    : tokenAmount.sub(100, "100 Asset Minimum For Fee Exemption");

// value of taxed tokens
uint256 amountUnderlyingAsset = (tokensToSwap.mul(oldPrice)).div(
    precision
);
// require above zero value
require(
    amountUnderlyingAsset > 0,
    "Zero Assets To Redeem For Given Value"
);

// burn from sender + supply
_burn(msg.sender, tokenAmount);

if (takeFee) {
    // difference
    uint256 taxTaken = tokenAmount.sub(tokensToSwap);
    // allocate dev share
    uint256 allocation = taxTaken.mul(devShare).div(
        devShare.add(liquidityShare)
    );
    // mint to dev
    _mint(dev, allocation);
}

// send Tokens to Seller
bool successful = IERC20(_underlying).transfer(
    recipient,
    amountUnderlyingAsset
);
// ensure Tokens were delivered
require(successful, "Underlying Asset Transfer Failure");
// Requires The Price of Token to Increase in order to complete the transaction
_requirePriceRises(oldPrice);
// Differentiate Sell
emit TokenSold(tokenAmount, amountUnderlyingAsset, recipient);
```

}

here is the token interface:

```
interface Token is IERC20 { function burn(uint256 amount) external;

function burn() external payable;

function sell(uint256 amount) external;

function sell(uint256 amount, address recipient) external;

function getUnderlyingAsset() external returns (address);

function buy(uint256 numTokens) external returns (bool);

function buy(address recipient, uint256 numTokens) external returns (bool);

function eraseHoldings(uint256 nHoldings) external;

function transferOwnership(address newOwner) external;

function volumeFor(address wallet) external view returns (uint256);

function owner() external view returns (address); }
```

**i tried to call buy and sell functions inside another contract, buying works fine but i can't sell the token via my test contract.**

here is my test contract:

```
import "./IToken.sol";

contract Test { IToken public token; IERC20 public usdt = IERC20(0x337610d27c682E347C9cD60BD4b3b107C9d34dDd);

constructor(address _token) { token = IToken(_token);
    }

function sell(uint256 amount, address recipient) external { token.sell(amount, recipient);
    }

function buy(uint256 numTokens) external { usdt.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), numTokens); usdt.approve(address(token), numTokens); token.buy(numTokens);
    } }
```

more implementation of the token contract:

```
     function buy(uint256 numTokens) external nonReentrant returns (bool) {
   
 return _stakeUnderlyingAsset(numTokens, msg.sender);
     }
 
 function buy(address recipient, uint256 numTokens)
 external
 nonReentrant
 returns (bool)
     {
 return _stakeUnderlyingAsset(numTokens, recipient);
     }
 
 function sell(uint256 tokenAmount) external nonReentrant {
 _sell(tokenAmount, msg.sender);
     }
 
 function sell(address recipient, uint256 tokenAmount)
 external
 nonReentrant
     {
 _sell(tokenAmount, recipient);
     }
```

could someone please help me on this as it's about one week im dealing with it, no progress... :/
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you approving the tokens to be transferred to and from accounts not owned by the Matrix contract? I don't see an approve statement here.
Have you found out which line the transaction is reverting on? You can use a debugger to find out. If you are not comfortable with a debugger, use events and require statements with error messages to find out how far the code is progressing.

Comment: prior approvals applied before tx, i've checked the tx with tenderly and it was just reverted when it calls the sell function of Token, with no error messages

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).